# Playing one <video> src after another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to play one `<video> src` after another -- cycling through a set of around 20 `<video>` elements.

Somehow everything seems to be working just fine for the first 1-2 cycles, but after that it jams up and the script starts skipping video files and slows down. Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my JS?

```
<video id="video-1" class="collage below" muted playsinline>
    <source src="video/collage-01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video id="video-2" class="collage above" muted playsinline>
    <source src="video/collage-02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video id="video-3" class="collage below" muted playsinline>
    <source src="video/collage-03.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

...
```

```
var allVideos = document.querySelectorAll('video.collage');
var count = 0;

function playVideos(e){
    if (count >= allVideos.length){
        count = 0;
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < allVideos.length; i++) {
        allVideos[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    
    allVideos[count].style.visibility = 'visible';
    allVideos[count].play();
    allVideos[count].addEventListener('ended', videoFinished, false);
    
    function videoFinished(e) {
        allVideos[count].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        count++;
        playVideos();
    }
}

playVideos();
```

Comment: in `videoFinished`, unset the eventListener. Since it recycles, it builds more listeners that'll mismatch with one and each other.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: That's why it clogs up. Sweet, thank you so much!